# WordPress replace content of a page (plugin)

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm writing a plugin that adds a page with a tag [deposit_page]; that tag should be replaced with some PHP code.

This is what I have, but it doesn't work. Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

```
function deposit_page_content($content) {
    $deposit_page_content = "here will go the content that should replace the tags";//end of variable deposit_page_content
    $content=str_ireplace('[deposit_page]',$deposit_page_content,$content);
return $content;
}
add_filter("the_content", "deposit_page_content");
```

I just noticed I gave the same variable name to the content that should replace the tag and the function itself. Could this be the problem?

Comment: That code works fine (I just tested it out by putting it in functions.php). How are you including this in your plugin? Is there any more functionality to your plugin? If not, I'd suggest simply pasting it in your functions file.

Comment: I did that, I just copy/pasted the function into functions.php of the default theme but still the same

Comment: are you using PHP5 ? str_ireplace is a PHP 5 function. 

As I say, I copied and pasted it into an existing wp-install over here and it works fine. On it's own, in the middle of a sentence ("test [deposit_page] test"), pretty much any configuration I can think of. It's perfectly valid code.

Comment: it's on wamp and so yes it's php 5. I'm going to try that out on another wordpress install

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WordPress has support for `[square_bracket_shortcodes]` built in.

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Here is your simple example:

```
function deposit_page_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $deposit_page_content = "here will go the content that should replace the tags";
    return $deposit_page_content;
}

add_shortcode( 'deposit_page', 'deposit_page_shortcode' );
```

You can paste this into your **active theme's** `functions.php` file.

If you wanted attributes, like `[my_shortcode foo=bar]`, you'd do, at the top of this function:

```
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'foo' => 'default foo',
    'example' => 'default example',
), $atts));

// Now you can access $foo and $example
```