# How to show text in a page on Wordpress whithin a plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am developing a plugin for a website.(Which is my first plugin for Wordpress)

The basic functionality is querying the database and in specific pages show the data from the database with a specific style instead of the content from the pages.

So far I managed to show some text in every specific page.

This is my code after some basic configurations:

```
global $wpdb;
global $wp_query;
add_action( 'wp', 'check_which_page' );
function check_which_page()
{

    $page_type=get_post_type();
    $page_id=get_the_ID();
    //echo $page_id;

    switch($page_id)
    {
        case 50:technologyPage();break;
        case 82:medicalPage();break;
    }   
}
function technologyPage()
{
    return print "Technology";
}
function salesPage()
{
    return print "Sales";
}
function medicalPage()
{
    return print "Medical";
}
```

I've read this post, but I couldn't solve my problem.
[WordPress replace content of a page (plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867490/wordpress-replace-content-of-a-page-plugin)

I already read the Wordpress documentation but I havent find anything there.

**I found myself a solution, using shortcodes.**

```
global $wpdb;
global $wp_query;
add_shortcode( 'sector_page_display', 'check_which_page' );
function check_which_page()
{

    $page_type=get_post_type();
    $page_id=get_the_ID();
    //echo $page_id;

    switch($page_id)
    {
        case 50:technologyPage();break;
        case 82:medicalPage();break;
    }   
}
function technologyPage()
{
    return print "Technology";
}
function medicalPage()
{
    return print "Medical";
}
```

See that instead of add_action I changed to add_shortcode

Then on everypage I will use to show info from the database I add

```
[sector_page_display]
```

in the page, so it call my method. You can add variables in there if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to run that code before WordPress has fully loaded.

Try this

```
global $wpdb;
global $wp_query;
add_action( 'init', 'check_which_page' );
function check_which_page()
{

    $page_type=get_post_type();
    $page_id=get_the_ID();
    //echo $page_id;

    switch($page_id)
    {
        case 50:technologyPage();break;
        case 82:medicalPage();break;
    }   
}
function technologyPage()
{
    return print "Technology";
}
function salesPage()
{
    return print "Sales";
}
function medicalPage()
{
    return print "Medical";
}
```

I changed the add_action to now run the code when WordPress is being initialized.

Comment: This solution hasn't worked. The text dissapeared instead of being at the top of the page. I am looking to move the text to the content area in the page.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/klEFgSv.png

Here you can see an image with the explanation.

Whit the code I used it shows the Technology text at the top of the page outside the template.

I need it to be where it normally shows the content from the page.
So it needs to replace the content of the page.